# Wall collision response results in jittery physics

Tags: physics, physics-engine

I have the following game loop :

```
while true {
    HandleInput()
    Update()
        PhysicsEngine.HandleCollisions()
        PhysicsEngine.Integrate()
    Render()
}
```

For now, `HandleCollisions` is simply negating the velocity vector of the player. The problem is that if I hold the button to walk forward this results in a jittery screen flashing between the render of the forward walk and the backward walk. How can I smooth it out so that it feels like the player has stopped even if I am still pressing the button ?

From what I have found on the internet, Unity's [Rigidbody.MovePosition](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html) solves this problem, but I was not able to find its implementation online.

One thing that I thought about, but am not sure if it is the solution is the following.

1. Find distance of penetration in the `HandleCollisions` function
2. In the same function move object this much
3. Change velocity to (0,0,0)

The problem here is that from my understanding the *Integration* step should be the one doing the movement and I should only be changing velocity. If that is correct, then I have no idea how to solve it.

edit : removed architecture tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing specifically what your two physics functions do, I suggest checking for the collision first before moving your player.

Consider the following example:

- Move player.x by 1
- Physics check
- Move player.x by -1
- Result: flicker

As compared to

- Physics check with potential movement (player.x + 1)
- Realise that there is a collision
- Set players velocity to 0
- Result: no flicker.

In the second case, since you are predicting if the player will collide with the wall before moving the player, there is no longer a need to push the player back, hence eliminating the flicker.

Comment: ty for the reply, the `Integrate` function does just that. `position += velocity * deltaTime`. The `HandleCollisions` simply negates the velocity of the object if it is colliding with something. As to what you said after, I am indeed checking the collisions before I integrate.

Comment: In that case, you just have to further debug to find out what is causing your animation to switch states. Which value is your animator referencing to decide to switch states?

Comment: I do not have animations implemented yet so I don't think that this is related to my problem. These are the steps that the program takes

**1. HandleInput** - sets a bunch of bools if the buttons are pressed

**2. Update** - sets the velocity of the objects based on the bools set in the previous step

**3. HandleCollisions** - checks if there are any overlapping objects and if so, it negates the velocity

**4. Integrate** - adds the `velocity * deltaTime` to the `position`

**5. Render**

**6. Start at step 1**

Comment: The problem is the fact that with the **button pressed** it means that on iteration X of `HandleCollisions` we have negative velocity and during the same iteration we push back the object during the integration step. On iteration X+1 the button is still pressed and so we set the velocity back to positive, we `HandleCollisions` but this time there are no collisions and so we move forward again. This becomes a loop and we go back to iteration X

Comment: How did you end up with negative velocity?

Comment: The `HandleCollisions` function negates the current velocity and the `Integrate` pushes the object back away from the box. My bad for saying negative velocity, it is simply negated and not negative.

Comment: Why would `Integrate` push the object back? If the velocity is set to 0 by `HandleCollision`

Comment: Integrate does not "push" the object, it is just moving it depending on the velocity. The `HandleCollisions` sets the velocity to the negative and then `Integrate` just moves it, it does not concern itself with where the object is and that sort of thing. I believe the problem is related to how much I push the object. Perhaps I can push it just enough to be on the edge rather than full on negating the current velocity. What do you think about that ? EDIT : thank you for the replies, appreciate it!

Comment: @MartinSpasov Look, you got to be a lot more concise in describing your issue. It would also be good for you to update your question with these details accordingly. As your `HandleCollision` function, the way I proposed you do it was to not move the object at all. Don't give the object a chance to go into the collider in the first place! Your velocity should never become negative, only to zero.

Comment: Got it, ill try again as it seems that I have misread the first point in the proposal (`Physics check with potential movement (player.x + 1)`) and if it works ill accept the answer.